# Dynamically re-size the rows for n-number of images, with all 5 rows consistent height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have five rows with images in a containers placed inside a container for each row .

Now, what i have been looking is

1. All 5 rows must be same height, in-spite of number of image containers in it.
2. For example first row has 5 image container and second row has 3 third row has 6 image containers respectively, still they should be of equal height, **in any resolution**
3. Here one row can have any number of images (different height and width) , but they should be in the image container with images align to the top, instead of center to help ease the jaggedness.
4. All images have different width and height, so while placed in image container their aspect ratio kept.
5. The width of depends on number of image containers in it, like 20 in first row should be wider in length , than 10 image containers in second row.

**html code**

```
<body>
<div>new</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-img">
  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
      <!--<!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<!--2nd row-->
<div>old</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-img">
  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

</div>
<!--3rd-->
<div>mid-level</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-img">
  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
     <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>


  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>
   <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- 4th-->
<div>older</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-img">
  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
     <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>
   <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- 5th-->
<div>oldest</div>
<div class="outer-wrap-img">
  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red">
     <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="red"><!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg" />-->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner-wrap-img">
    <div class="green">
      <!--<img src="http://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg" />-->
</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
.outer-wrap-img {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.inner-wrap-img {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 2px;
}
.inner-wrap-img div {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  position: relative;
}
.inner-wrap-img div img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.red {
 /* background: #F00;*/
  background-color:#CCC
}
.green {
  /*background: #0f0;*/
  background-color:#CCC
}
```

[Fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/0ynus26k/3/)

Comment: So what JS have you tried...because you'll need it?

Comment: So no overflow, correct? You want each image shrunk, keeping it's aspect ratio, to fit within the image container, that is based on the number of images?

Comment: exactly @Twisty, images should keep the aspect ratio in image container which dimensions are based on number of images in a row

Comment: @Paulie_D i have tried , but i am not sure what to do

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any Javascript, I'll write some pseudo-code for you

```
function doResize(){
   //for each parent div
      resize(parent div, images in div);
}

function resize(parent, images){
    var imageHeight = parentheight / image number;
    //adjust images to imageheight
}
```

Comment: can u provide a jsfiddle example

Comment: @sampu This isn't a place where people write all your code for you.